# Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in includes/database/database.inc on line 813

Tags: 7, wsod

```
Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in /home/content/71/11241671/html/drupal/includes/database/database.inc on line 813
```

We built a site in a subfolder called /drupal while building the site, and then moved the files to the root directory when we were finished but it gave the above error on a WSOD.

I have tried:

- flushing the cache before moving
- tried the registry rebuild
- truncating and replacing the registry and registry_file tables with a fresh install copy, and rebuilding the registry again
- rewrite base in htaccess
- setting a new base url in settings.php

But nothing has worked.

The second we put the files back into the /drupal folder, it works again. It also looks like the error mentions the file in the /drupal directory, which isnt there anymore.

This is on 7.37

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling back this patch... https://www.drupal.org/node/2170453 solved the first problem, and then using htaccess to define the correct php version fixed the next error.