# Moved Drupal site trying to load old directory

Tags: 7, installation, bootstrapping

I've been building a Drupal site in a subdomain/directory called "new". I've now gone to move the site to the root, so it loads on www and the website will not load, instead giving the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in /usr/www/redacted/public/new/includes/database/database.inc on line 813

To be clear, it was located in /public/new, now it's just in /public.

Why oh why is it still trying to load stuff from the old folder? Is Drupal 7.37.
Thanks

Comment: Did you create the 'new' folder or did it already exist?  The hosting company may have your apache directory/vhost pointing to the 'new' folder unless you were the one that created it. Also check settings.php for a rewrite rule including new.

Comment: Did you try all these?

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158794/fatal-error-class-selectquery-not-found-in-includes-database-database-inc-on

Comment: New folder was one auto-created when I made a "new" subdomain, with the old site active on the root (www). I did try rolling back the patch, but it made no difference.

Comment: No rewrite rules in settings.php that I can see. Almost everything in there is commented out.

Comment: It's likely an apache configuration then, you'll need to keep the "new" folder or ask your hosting company to change the doc root to public.  There shouldn't be any issue with having the site in /public/new if that is the doc root.  You would do the www vs. non-www redirects in your .htaccess

Comment: Rewrite rules would normally go in a .htaccess file.  Check settings.php to see if $base_url is set